# Auto Dismiss Bootstrap Alert stopped working in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I was using the following code to automatically dismiss success alerts in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
$ ->
  flashCallback = ->
    $(".alert-success").fadeOut()
  $(".alert-success").bind 'click', (ev) =>
    $(".alert-success").fadeOut()
  setTimeout flashCallback, 3000
```

With the relevant alert line of:

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == "notice" ? "success" : "danger" %> alert-dismissable">
```

Everything was working great but it seems to have broken somewhere along the way.

All of my code can be found here: https://github.com/vroomanj/updemo

Is there a better way of accomplishing what I want to accomplish? Does anyone see anything wrong with what I am doing which might have caused it to stop working? I wish I could say when it stopped working but I Just now noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Noty http://ned.im/noty/#/about

This is how i used it

add this code to application.js.coffee

```
window.show_notification = (text, type)->
  n = noty({
    layout: 'topRight'
    text: text
    type: type
    theme: 'relax'
    animation:
      open: "animated bounceInRight"
      close: "animated fadeOut"
  })
  setTimeout (->
      n.close()
    ), 5000
```

My Flash message partial in slim format

```
javascript:
  if(#{flash[:notice].present?}){
    show_notification("<span class= 'fa fa-check-circle'></span> #{flash[:notice]}", 'success')
  }

  if(#{flash[:alert].present?}){
    show_notification("<span class= 'fa fa-exclamation-circle '></span> #{flash[:alert]}", 'error')
  }
```